# How to edit prior line in ghci's multi-line mode?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Using `ghci`, I sometimes enter definitions using multi-line mode (as described in the [interactive-evaluation documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html)).

For instance,

```
> :{
Prelude| sumToN :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a
Prelude| sumToN n
Prelude|   | signum n /= 1 = 0
Prelude|   | otherwise = 1 + sumToN (n-1)
Prelude| :}
>
```

When using this multi-line input mode, I occasionally realize that I have made a mistake in my input on a previous line. For example, in this code I accidentally typed `A` instead of `a`.

```
> :{
Prelude| sumToN :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> A
Prelude|
```

To correct the mistake I need to edit a prior line. However, I cannot find any way to go back and edit a previous line. Instead, I `^C` out of the multi-line mode and start again, repeating if necessary until I type the whole definition line-by-line without mistakes.

**Is there any way to edit a previous line in `ghci`'s multi-line mode without having to type all lines again?**

Comment: You can't - just type your code into a file and load that file.

Comment: I'd love if multi-line mode entered a real editor mode where 1) you can still see the lines above and 2) you can move freely in the bottom part of the screen as in a regular editor. Alas, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. GHCi uses [Haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline), which only works on a per-line basis (and does not provide `C-x C-e` as GNU Bash does). Essentially, GHCi just works through [a queue of lines](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs#L948-L971), which use [Haskeline's `getInputLine`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs#L636-L646).

So `:{` and `:}` only take your code, add `"\n"` inbetween your lines, and then "run it trough the interpreteter". There's no line-buffer you can edit, unfortunately. All you can do is to discard the lines with `C-c` and try again.